# How to move directory to another directory using git

Tags: git, git-mv

I have one directory 'Checkout' that needs to move to the directory 'screens'. I do not want to overwrite the screens folder, I just want to add Checkout to it. This is all on local machine.

So far I have created and navigated to a new branch. The idea is to move the entire directory in this branch, add/commit the changes then push this branch with the changed directory location to remote.

I have tried this command...

`git mv app/Checkout ... app/screens`

but I get

`fatal: bad source, source=..., destination=app/screens/...`

What am I missing?

Comment: Does source exist? Are you in the correct working directory? (verify with `ls app/Checkout`)

Comment: Note you can just move the files outside of Git. When you stage up all the adds and deletes, Git will detect them as moves before you commit.

Comment: Is there any good reasons for the three dots in your command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you want is `git mv app/Checkout app/screens`. The triple dots in the docs indicate that you can provide multiple source arguments, not literal dots.

Answer (score 2):

The error `fatal: bad source ...` usually indicates that after last commit there were some renames in the source directory and hence `git mv` can‘t find the expected file. Just `git commit` before execute `git mv`.

And why `…`? You can simple execute the `git mv`-command as follow:

```
git mv app/Checkout app/screens
```

Look at [Git-docu](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)